# timing and redirecting subprocess:PIPE output to file

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, stdout, timing

I'm trying to execute a bash and want to redirect the output on the shell to a file

this is what I have so far

```
baby = subprocess.Popen('some command', stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
print (baby.stdout.readlines()) #i wanna see it in console
with open("log.txt","a") as fobj: #wanna create a file log.txt and save the output there as string                                 
        fobj.write(stdout)
```

but I get this error `NameError: name 'stdout' is not defined`

I've looked at these question [Run subprocess and print output to logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21953835/run-subprocess-and-print-output-to-logging) , [subprocess.Popen() doesn't redirect output to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50111465/subprocess-popen-doesnt-redirect-output-to-file) , [Can you make a python subprocess output stdout and stderr as usual, but also capture the output as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270645/can-you-make-a-python-subprocess-output-stdout-and-stderr-as-usual-but-also-cap?noredirect=1&lq=1) but to no avail, they were all too complex for me, i got lost in all the code..

can't i just redirect the stdout to a normal txt file? 
and is there a way I can built a function to time the execution of that script and put it in that same log.txt file (i use `time ./myscript.py` to take the time but i also don't know how to redirect it to the txt file)

Answer (score 0):

You should adjust this example however suits you

First create input.txt file

Then

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as input, open(sys.argv[2], 'w') as output:
    for line in input:
        output.write(str(line.strip()) + '\n')
```

You run it from command line(s4.py,you can rename it)

```
python s4.py input.txt output.txt
```

Output

```
obama
is
my boss
```

You can guess but output is same as input.